# RRD calcula mal los promedios (AVERAGE)

Tags: xml, perl

Sobre un fichero **RRD** (Round Rubin Database), con **Perl** y **rrdTools** estoy exportando a **XML** (DUMP), quitando del mismo todos los datos desde una fecha dada, restaurando (RESTORE), redimensionando de vuelta a los valores iniciales (RESIZE) y añadiendo los míos propios (UPDATE).

Al finalizar, comparo ambos ficheros y son idénticos exceptuando los datos modificados. Si hago un volcado, los XML también.

Están configuradas cuatro agregaciones de 5 minutos, 30 minutos, 2 horas y un día y, siendo la primera y la segunda correctas con respecto a los datos modificados y sin modificar, sorprendentemente las medias de dos horas y la diaria da un dato incorrecto en las franjas modificadas, mayor a cualquiera de los participantes en esa media.

Es como si, para hallar la media, en lugar de dividir por el número de sumandos, no tuviera en cuenta alguno de ellos y, dándole vueltas una y otra vez, no encuentro qué posible combinación de sumandos y divisor está empleando intentando encontrar dónde se está liando.

Por supuesto, el resto del fichero sí realiza bien el resto de medias en las zonas de datos que no he modificado (aunque quizá si cortado y repuesto, es decir, añadido tras una franja de datos modificados pero idénticos a los originales).

¿A alguien le ha pasado algo similar?
¿Hay algún valor de configuración que tenga que tener en cuenta?

Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Una posible causa es la pérdida de información debido a la presencia de datos desconocidos en los periodos de tiempo más pequeños. Si no hay datos conocidos suficientes, rrdtool descartará todo el periodo.

Por defecto, en muchos sistemas tienen definido un descarte del periodo considerado si el número de datos es inferior al 50 %. Ejemplo sacado de un rrddump:

```
<rra>                                                    
        <cf>AVERAGE</cf>                                 
        <pdp_per_row>1</pdp_per_row> <!-- 300 seconds -->

        <params>                                         
        <xff>5.000000000e-01</xff>                       
        </params>
```

El factor **xff** define qué parte del intervalo de consolidación puede componerse de datos desconocidos (UNKNOWN) y seguir considerando el valor consolidado como conocido. Es decir: el porcentaje de datos mínimos que se necesitan en un determinado periodo para considerar que cuenta con datos suficientes como para hacer la consolidación para el periodo mayor. Si está puesto al 50 %, entonces ese es el máximo de datos desconocidos permitidos. Si se supera esa marca, todo el periodo se marca como desconocido para la consolidación superior.

Más información en **man rrdcreate**

Comment: Datos no faltan. Por cada uno que elimino, tras restaurar y redimensionar, añado otro. Si tras realizar el proceso, vuelvo a hacer un dump, la única diferencia entre los ficheros XML son los datos y agregados del rango modificado. El problema que calcula mal agregados AVERAGE de dos horas y diario (el de 30 minutos es correcto, lo más extraño de todo, porque entendería que hay errores si todo estuviera mal, pero sólo una parte ... )